# Does volatile synchronise an array of atomic data types?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, volatile, atomic

I wonder if the following structure is safe-thread. I know that I should synchronize all accesses to `enc` (read, write, adding/substracting). But I'd like to know if the boolean arrays are safe. They change constantly by many different threads. I certainly talk about the array elements and not the array reference.

```
public class SimBox {

    public static final int HP = 100;
    public static final int LP = 35;

    public static volatile boolean[] ins = new boolean[16];
    public static volatile boolean[] outs = new boolean[16];

    public static volatile int enc = 0;

}
```

**Note:** In this case I don't need to reinitialize the arrays. I only read and write their elements. I wonder if I should declare them final too?!

What are they for?

To simulate a hardware/mechanical machine movements.

- There are some threads that update `outs` fields according the
  realtime content of ins fields.
- There are some threads that change `ins` fields according `enc` value and and some other external factors.
- There is a unique thread that updates `enc` by adding/substracting `HP` or `LP` according to output and input threads.
- There are some other threads that read `enc` value and take their decisions for other parts of the program or for changing `outs`.
- It's quiet important that all these data be available to read/write at most after 40ms. Otherwise there will be some anomolies.

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? `volatile` only guarantees that a thread reading `ins` or `outs` will see the most recent value written into the variable. That's not the same as safety.

Comment: if it treats the boolean elements of the array as boolean variables, then it's enough. Because the operation on a boolean var is atomic. I either write or read a true or false! @ChrisHayes btw, I edited the question and added a note.

Comment: Atomic operations are operations that are supported by CPU as atomic. You have an array and for instance ins[x] = y ; is not an atomic operation. If you specify little bit more what you would like to do with the data structure, it would be possible to say if  volatile is enough of it would be better to use something from java.concurrency.

Comment: @JosefN I added more information if you find it useful!

Comment: @Johnny thx, it is not so complicated, HP, LP can be changed to AtomicInteger and to keep performance ins and outs to AtomicReference. Threads than make copy of them, calculate new values and assign new value using compareAndSet(). If compareAndSet() does not succeeded the thread repeats: make copy, calculate new values and try once more. It looks weird but it is far faster then synchronization or using locks. I can make an example if you are interested. Happy Xmas :)

Comment: @JosefN :D But I think you didn't read the updates that asked me :D HP and LP are completely out of discussion. They are pure global constants. Only ins, outs and enc can change! And that's because they are not even volatile!

Comment: @Johnny Sorry I've misread the third point :) HP and LP are final so they are thread safe. OK are you interested in example with arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does volatile synchronise an array of atomic data types?

No.  However, your example is not using atomic data types.

> I wonder if the following structure is safe-thread (sic).

No, it is not.  There are lots of ways that that data structure could be accessed / updated that would not be thread-safe.

> I wonder if I should declare them final too?!

That would be a good idea, but it doesn't make the arrays thread-safe.

---

If you want to achieve thread-safe access and update to an array (without using `synchronized`), you should look at the atomic array classes.  There are three of them: `AtomicIntegerArray`, `AtomicLongArray` and `AtomicReferenceArray`.  You could also potentially use ordinary (unsynchronized) arrays of `AtomicBoolean` ... provided that the array's were safely published to the threads and never updated by them.

But it is not clear to me that atomic arrays that are "randomly" changed by lots of threads are going to be usable for your purposes.  For a start, atomic arrays do not provide a way to get a consistent snapshot of the array for analysis purposes.  The only way you can achieve that is to "pause" or "stop" all of the threads while your (hypothetical) code examines the atomic array.

If you need to get consistent snapshots without explicitly stopping / pausing everything, you may be better off using `synchronized` rather than "atomic" types.

Comment: Their changes are random from this question part of view. I should implement thousands of lines to simulate their behaviour. FYI. they are the ports of this device http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?product_id=1012

Comment: Do you mean that I should use synchronized getIns() or synchronized getIns(int i) ? / I mean the same for the setters. However I note that the correct simulation will be for getIns(int i) because the phidgets libraries have only this kind of method.

Comment: @Johnny - I think you really need to get a copy of "Java Concurrency In Practice" by Goetz et al.  (I noticed a downloadable PDF when I googled it ...)